# Dependent Rails model in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, mocking, factory-bot

I'm refactoring specs to support a migration of a string to a foreign key in a new table.

Questions had a string, type, which is now a new table: question_types.  The factory is configured to use a random string for the value of type. How can I update it so that there are 5 valid types that it can be assigned as needed?

What I tried to do was update the question factory with

```
## questions.rb
factory.define do
  before(:create) do 
    FactoryGirl.create(:question_types) if QuestionType.all.empty?
  end

# ...more factory

end

## question_types.rb
FactoryGirl :question do
  factory :question_type do
    category 'multiple_choice'
  end

  factory :question_types do
    [
      { label: 'Single Choice', category: 'single_choice' },
      { label: 'Multiple Choice', category: 'multiple_choice' },
      # ... more types here
    ].each do |h|
      FactoryGirl.create(:question_type, h)
    end
  end
end
```

But when I run the specs, the value of question type is always nil.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sample in your Factory definition:

```
question_type { Question.all.types.sample }
```